# Porting from libevent to boost::asio: what is a direct equivalent of libevent's event in ASIO?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-asio

*I'm trying to backport a libevent-based library to use ASIO backend (thus avoid multiple event loops in single application). There are other ways to solve the "problem", but I'm interested in this one*

I don't see a direct equivalent of `event` object (or, rather, a handle - because libevent is written in plain C) in Boost::ASIO documentation; *boost::asio::strand looks* familiar, but it doesn't seem to follow libevent's pattern: create, expect, receive, do work {, repeat }.

What I need is to have a set of object / event / event callback, which can be created and forgotten unless callback (by socket event) happens, running on top of `io_service`'s loop; is there anything like that in Boost?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Boost.Asio does not provide an equivalent to the libevent's [events](http://www.wangafu.net/~nickm/libevent-book/Ref4_event.html).

In Boost.Asio, one creates an I/O object, such as a [`socket`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/ip__tcp/socket.html) (1).  The program will then initiate an operation, such as [`socket.async_receive(buffer, &handler)`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/async_receive/overload1.html) (2) to indicate that it wants data to be read from the socket into `buffer`, and invoke `handler` after data has been read.  This step is similar to creating a non-persistent *pending* event in libevent, but one key difference is that Boost.Asio's [Proactor](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/async.html) will read data from the socket into `buffer` on behalf of the user, rather than informing the user that data is available to be read.  Finally, Boost.Asio will forward the request to the operating system (3).

[image]

The operation system will then notify the `io_service` that data is available to read (4) in a similar fashion to when a libevent event becomes *active*.  At some point, the application will process the event loop via [`io_service::run()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/run/overload1.html) (5), just like one would do with libevent's `event_base_loop()`.  As data is available to be read, Boost.Asio will read data from the socket into `buffer`, then post user's callback (`handler`) into a queue of callbacks ready to invoked (6).  The application will then invoke the callback while processing the event loop.

[image]

Boost.Asio puts a strong focus on the I/O object rather than the operations:

- An operation must be initiated each time the application is interested in handling an event on an I/O object.  In this regard, the overall flow would be akin to a libevent program only using non-persistent events.
- Operations are not identifiable.  Boost.Asio does not provide the same level of control that libevent provides for operations.  For example, if an application has a *pending* read event and *pending* write event on a socket, libevent allows the write event to be removed via `event_free()` without affecting the read event.  On the other hand, with operations not being identifiable in Boost.Asio, one can only cancel all pending operations, such as via [`socket.cancel()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/basic_stream_socket/cancel/overload1.html), rather than being able to cancel a specific operation, such as a write but not a read.

---

<sub>Source images and general details can located [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost_asio/overview/core/basics.html).</sub>